# Prepare content does not work for Sourcerer and DirectPHP

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla3.0

In my Joomla website, I need to execute some custom SQL queries, that have to select different titles from related categories.

Problem I have it works like option Prepare Content is turned off, so all of my content is outside HTML tags.

Module content looks like this:

```
{source}
<?php
$var_result = '';
$var_categories = array();
$var_category_list = array();
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'select * from jneg_categories where parent_id = 9';
$db->setQuery($query,0,300);
$res = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ( $res as $row ) {
    $var_categories[($row->id)] = $row->title;
    $var_category_list[] = $row->id;
}
$var_category_list = implode($var_category_list, ', ');
$sql = "select * from jneg_content where catid IN (".$var_category_list.") order by `catid`";
$db->setQuery($sql,0,30000);
$res = $db->loadObjectList();
$var_current_cat = 0;
foreach ( $res as $row ) {
    if ($current_cat != $row->catid) {
        $current_cat = $row->catid;
        echo '<h2>'.$categories[($row->catid)] . '</h2>';
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo $row->title;
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
{/source}
```

Can you help me how to get proper HTML as a result of this code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it with Jumi plugin - http://2glux.com/projects/jumi/usage-for-j15

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sourcer or other php rendering plugins don't run in html modules unless you go under the module 'options' and select 'prepare content'...

...or you can use this module and just include your php file directly:

https://github.com/idea34/mod_show